# Something like $AssertFunction=Abort[];Message[] 

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to customize the new Assert to print message as it usually does, but to also Abort[] all computation. Abort[] part is easy, but how do I generate the same message as the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$AssertFunction = (Message[Assert::asrtf, #1]; Abort[]) &
```